# How to count page views in MySQL without performance hit

Tags: mysql, performance

I want to count the amount of visitors of a page, similar to what stackoverflow is doing with the "views" of each question.

The current solution just increments a field of a InnoDB table:

```
UPDATE data SET readers = readers + 1, date_edited = date_edited    WHERE ID = '881529' LIMIT 1
```

This is the most expensive query on the page since it is performing a write operation.

Is there a better solution to the problem? How do high traffic sites like stackoverflow handle this?

I am thinking to instead write to a table using the memory engine and writing that content to a innodb table every minute or so.

e.g.:

```
INSERT INTO mem_table (id,views_new)
VALUES (881525,1)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE views_new = views_new+1
```

Then I would run a cron job every minute to update the InnoDB table:

```
UPDATE data d, mem_table m
SET d.readers = d.readers + m.readers_new   
WHERE d.ID = m.ID;

DELETE FROM mem_table;
```

Unfortunatelly this is not so good with replication and the application is using a MySQL Galera Cluster.

Thank you in advance for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

There are ways to reduce the immediate performance hit by starting a separate thread to update your counters. When you have a high number of parallel users (so many parallel updates of your hit counters), it is  advisable to use a queuing mechanism to prevent locking (so like your in memory table). Your queue will have both writes and reads, so you have to take the table and data design into account.

Alternative is keeping a counter related to the article in a separate file. This prevents congestion on the single table with hit counters or if you keep it in the table serving the articles: A high lock wait time out on that article table (resulting in all kind of front end errors). Keeping the data in separate files does not give you insight in the overall hits on your site, but for that you could just use a log graphing tool like awstats.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I am not sure though if I understood your suggestion right. Do you recommend to store the info inside a file on the file system? Wouldn't this be a serious perf hit?

Comment: Appending to a file is not a "serious" perf hit.

Comment: Files are cached by the OS also before write, so the file solution is a non-crash proof solution: Some writes could get lost. It is (assuming a sufficient amount of IO is available) a workable solution preventing "cross" locks (cross lock: article A update blocks actions on article B etc).

Answer (score 0):

If you can batch 100 `INSERTs`/`UPDATEs` together in a single statement, you can run it 10 times as fast.  (There is a risk of `lock_wait_timeout` and/or deadlock.)

What if you build a `MEMORY` table and lose the queued data in a power failure?  I assume that is OK for this application?  (If not, you have a much bigger problem.)

What are your client(s)?  Can they queue up things before even touching the database?

I like ping-ponging a pair of tables for staging data into the database.  Clients write to one table; a continuously running job (not a cron job) is working with the other table.  When the latter finishes with inserts/updates, it swaps the tables with a single, atomic, `RENAME TABLE` so that the clients are oblivious.  [My Staging Table blog](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/staging_table) discusses this in further detail.  It explains how to avoid the replication problems you encountered.

Another tip.  Do not put the count and date in the main table.  Put them in a 'parallel table' ('vertical partitioning').  This cuts down on the bulkiness in replication and decreases the interference with other processing.

For Galera, use a pair non-replicated tables (suggest MyISAM with no indexes).  Have the continually running job run in one place, cycling through the 3 nodes.  If you had 3 jobs, there would be several ways in which they are more likely to stumble over each other.

If this won't keep up, you need to Shard your data.  (That's what the big folks do, sooner or later.)

Comment: If the info gets lost it does not really matter. I have now one cron job that adresses the cluster every minute through HAProxy in round robin fashion. This means that the info should be updated on average every 3 minutes in a 3 node cluster. The request time on pageload is now about 3-5ms shorter on an idle server.

Comment: A risk with a cron job is that if it, for whatever reason, runs for more than a minute, it will bump into the next cron invocation.  Then may stumble over each other and either mess up the data or get slower and slower, never catching up.